# How to fold all comments in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, code-folding

I've recently been editing files with a lot of long comments. I find myself folding lots of them manually, is there a way to fold all of these at once, using some kind of menu entry or keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Try Code | Folding | Collapse doc comments

Comment: @yole Really strange but it didn't do anything for me, I tried 2 different projects, both with all text selected and no text selected. Does it usually work for you? This is pycharm 5.0.4.

Answer (score 13):

As of writing (version 2016.2.3) there's no way to collapse just comments.

The closest is the `Code > Folding > Expand all to level` menu items, but that folds everything by level. There are 5 levels available, with keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad *</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> (Press Ctrl+Shift+Numpad *, then press 1. On macOS substitute Command for Ctrl)

  [image]
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad *</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>

  [image]
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad *</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>

  [image]
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad *</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>

  [image]
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad *</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>

  [image]

Answer (score 5):

I came to this question recently with the same one, but I've ince found it is possible to do this in recent pycharms. In pycharm 2020.3 (and possibly earlier versions, but that's the one I'm using), there is now an option to "Collapse Doc Comments", which appears to do what you need! It collapsed all the docstring comments in my file and ignored all other collapsible portions of code.

`Code` -> `Folding` -> `Collapse Doc Comments`

[image]

Comment: +1. From my first comment I don't think it worked many years ago, but it now appears to work fine for me, so guessing they fixed some bug. However it doesn't appear to work for long multi-line comments, which can be manually collapsed one-by-one.

Answer (score 2):

Press (Command) and +(key) to expand and use -(key) to collapse

Comment: Thanks, but I would like a solution for all comments.

Comment: Goto Code>Folding and there you can select the level of folding which you prefer

Answer (score -2):

try shift+ctrl+= Expand all folding regions.